# MVVM best practice vs keeping things simple

Tags: wpf, mvvm

The first code section below is the code I am tempted to write. The second code section below is what a previous code worker wrote when trying to achieve the same task.

The previous co-worker's code seems to follow standard MVVM practice on having a seperate ViewModel for each type of item, of keeping track of SelectedItems in the ViewModel rather than the view, and of avoiding ObservableCollection in the model.

The code I am tempted to write is about half the size and complexity, with less potential for the model and ViewModel getting out of sync, and far less lines of code.

Is MVVM best practice really the right answer here? Is there some sort of middle ground combining the best of both versions?

My code:

```
//Model

public class Cheese
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Tastiness { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class CheeseEditorModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Cheese> Cheeses { get; private set; }

    public CheeseEditorModel()
    {
        //read cheeses in from file/database/whatever
    }

    public DeleteCheeses(SelectedObjectCollection selected)
    {
        //delete cheeses
    }
}

//ViewModel

public class CheeseEditorViewModel
{
    private CheeseEditorModel _model;
    public ObservableCollection<Cheese> Cheeses { get {return _model.Cheeses} }

    public CheeseEditorViewModel()
    {
        _model = new CheeseEditorModel();
    }

    public DeleteSelected(SelectedObjectCollection selected)
    {
        _model.Delete(selected);
    }
}

//XAML

<ListBox Name="CheeseListBox" ItemsSource={Binding Path="Cheeses"} />
<Button Command={Binding DeleteSelected} CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CheeseListBox, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

Other person's code:

```
//Model

public class Cheese
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Tastiness { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class CheeseEditorModel
{
    public List<Cheese> Cheeses { get; private set; }

    public CheeseDataModel()
    {
        //read cheeses in from file/database/whatever
    }

    public DeleteCheeses(IEnumerable<Cheese> toDelete)
    {
        //delete cheeses
    }
}

//ViewModel

public class CheeseViewModel
{
    private Cheese _cheese { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public CheeseViewModel(Cheese cheese)
    {
        _cheese = cheese;
        IsSelected = false;
    }

    public string Name {get {return _cheese.Name} set { _cheese.Name = value } }
    public int Tastiness {get {return _cheese.Tastiness} set { _cheese.Tastiness= value } }
    public Color Color {get {return _cheese.Color} set { _cheese.Color = value } }
}

public class CheeseEditorViewModel
{
    private CheeseEditorModel _model;
    public ObservableCollection<CheeseViewModel> Cheeses { get; private set; }

    public CheeseEditorViewModel()
    {
        _model = new CheeseEditorModel();
        foreach (cheese in _model.Cheeses)
            Cheeses.Add(cheese);
    }

    public DeleteSelected()
    {
        var selected = from cheese in Cheeses select cheese.CheeseModel where cheese.IsSelected();
        _model.Delete(selected);
        var selectedVM = from cheese in Cheeses select cheese where cheese.IsSelected();
        foreach (cheese in selectedVM)
            Cheeses.Remove(selected);
    }
}

//XAML

<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Path="Cheeses"}>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
<Button Command={Binding DeleteSelected} />
```

Comment: Insulation of a Model object within a ViewModel object for presentation (such as this case) is loosely akin to insulation of a field data member within a property.  It's extra overhead when you don't need to do anything other than simple data access, but it comes in handy later when you want to add additional complexity in-between.

Comment: In your code, in the getter of `CheeseEditorViewModel.Cheeses`, how do you convert `ObservableCollection<Cheese>` to `ObservableCollection<CheeseViewModel>`?

Comment: @fmunkert: a typo, in my code there is no `CheeseViewModel` in my code, so it is just an `ObservableCollection<Cheese>`

Answer (score 0):

does Cheese implement INotifyPropertyChanged? if yes why? but nevertheless i go with the other's person code. you can easily add new non model related stuff

Comment: Cheese doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, because the application is sufficiently simple that no-one needs to know about updates other than the UI element which made the change. But yes, thinking about it my version doesn't really properly separate the model from the rest of the program, I will abandon my idea.